# Check if at least 2 values from a list are in another list

Tags: python, list, contains

I have a list a:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

and list b1:

```
["a", "b", "x"]
```

and b2:

```
["a", "z", "x"]
```

If b1 has at least 2 elements from a the result is True.
If b2 has at least 2 elements from a the result is True.

In this example b1 == True and b2 == False.

How can I check that in Python?

Comment: Convert the two lists to sets. Get the intersection. Get the length of the intersection.

Comment: If b1 equals `["a","a","x"]` then converting to a set may not give the correct answer

Comment: does the elements need to be unique?

Comment: The elements in each list are unique in my case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function should do what you want, using sets and [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection).

```
def f(a, b):
    return len(set(a) & set(b)) >= 2
```

Usage:

```
>>> f(a, b1)
True
>>> f(a, b2)
False
```

Alternatively, if `b` has repeated elements, you could use:

```
def f2(a, b):
    return sum(x in a for x in b) >= 2
```

Test:

```
>>> f(a, ['a', 'a', 'x'])
False
>>> f2(a, ['a', 'a', 'x'])
True
```